# How can I test a regular variable against a specific array value?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to test a variable against a specific/all possible values within an array?
For instance, if I have:

```
var abc;
var array1 = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];

function someFunction(){
  abc = "item2"
  if (abc == !!**Either array1[item1] OR array1[item2] OR.. etc for x in array1**!!)
    {
      //*do stuff*
    }
}
```

What is the correct syntax for testing `abc` against any possible entry in `array1`?

Comment: If you're just talking simple strings, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript) for lost of ways to do a "contains" in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *syntax* for this, you need to loop over the array and compare values indiviually.

```
function  somefunction(){
  abc = "item2"

  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i) {
    if (abc == array1[i]) {
      //*do stuff*
    }
  }
}
```

A common way of shortening this (in the case where your test is for simple equality) is to use the built-in `indexOf` function, which returns the index of the item in the array, or `-1` if it wasn't found.

```
if (array1.indexOf(abc) != -1) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a loop:

```
for(i in array1){
  if(abc === array1[i]){
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Be careful when using `for .. in` - if you've defined anything in the prototype, you'll get unexpected results - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 0):

Use `indexOf()` to check what position the value appears at in the array.  If it returns -1, then the value doesn't exist.

```
if (array1.indexOf(abc) != -1) {
  // do stuff...
}
```